# Keep css right arrow same size on different zoom levels

Tags: html, css

I have a right arrow in my css and I am trying to keep the size of the arrow to be the same on 100% zoom and 80% zoom level. Currently it is changing size when I zoom to 80%.

The other arrows I have like a top arrow or left arrow don't do this.

I made a stackblitz of it here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mdhw4t?file=src/app/app.component.css

Here is my code

```
.arrow-box {
  border: 4px solid #1a202c;
  position: relative;
  right: 35%;
  background: #1a202c;
}

.arrow-box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    left: 97%;
    top: 40%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow-box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-left-color: #1a202c;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

.arrow-box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-left-color: #1a202c;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-top: -36px;
}



.stay-invested-tip {
  background-color: #1a202c;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  margin-left: 570px;
  margin-top: 753px;
  width: 35%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 260px;
  padding: 0%;
}


<div class="pop-up-wrap" >
    <div class="savings-tip arrow-box sm:mt-6 sm:p-4">
        <div>
        <p class="font-hairline text-2xl leading-tight mb-1 connect-advice-font-title">View the impact on your financial future if you move your savings</p>
        <p class="connect-advice-font-title less-padding weight-400">See how your projected retirement (age and income), on the right, will be affected as you move the slider.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-row my-4 float-left got-it-btn-div">
        <button  class="connect-advice-btn font-semibold mr-12 w-2/5 text-sm shadow-md text-center right-0 p-2 rounded-full text-white uppercase cursor-pointer weight-400">got it</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At 100% it looks like this
[image]

At 80% it looks like this
[image]

But like I said, if I make a top arrow or left arrow, then this does not happen

Comment: This is due to the fact, that the pseudo element is positioned at `left: 97%;` – so when the container element width changes, that in turn changes how much of the triangle gets hidden behind the container. Position the pseudo element at a full 100%, and then move it back over the the left by the desired amount of pixels, like `left: calc(100% - 20px)` or something.

Comment: @CBroe ah thank you, please mark as answer and I will mark as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact, that the pseudo element is positioned at `left: 97%;` – so when the container element width changes, that in turn changes how much of the triangle gets hidden behind the container.

Position the pseudo element at a full 100%, and then move it back over to the left by the desired amount of pixels, like `left: calc(100% - 20px)` or something.